# Read bytes from pixels - libGDX

Tags: java, image-processing, libgdx

**H**ow can I convert given `Pixmap` into byte array ?

```
byte[] bytes = Gdx.files.internal("image.png").readBytes();

// pass the correct bytes into pixmap
Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

byte[] sameBytes = new byte[SIZE];
int count = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < pixmap.getWidth(); x++) {
     for (int y = 0; y < pixmap.getHeight(); y++) {
          int pixel = pixmap.getPixel(x, y);

          sameBytes[count++] = ((pixel >> 24) & 0xff);
          sameBytes[count++] = ((pixel >> 16) & 0xff);
          sameBytes[count++] = ((pixel >>  8) & 0xff);
          sameBytes[count++] = ((pixel      ) & 0xff);
     }
}

// sameBytes is not correct bytes into pixmap
Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(sameBytes, 0, sameBytes.length);
```

> Couldn't load pixmap from image data

Comment: @Squiddie Problem of these lines of code it doesn't run on HTML project.

Comment: I have raw data not encoded data this is my main problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might work

```
for (int x = 0; x < pixmap.getWidth(); x++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < pixmap.getHeight(); y++)
    int pixel = pixmap.getPixel(x, y);
    sameBytes[count++] = ((pixel & 0xff000000) >>> 24);
    sameBytes[count++] = ((pixel & 0x00ff0000) >>> 16);
    sameBytes[count++] = ((pixel & 0x0000ff00) >>> 8);
    sameBytes[count++] = ((pixel & 0x000000ff));
  }
}
```